How to implement a custom coroutine dispatcher for specific threading models in Kotlin?
I'm working on a Kotlin project where I need to implement a custom coroutine dispatcher. The requirement is to have a dispatcher that utilizes a specific threading model rather than the standard ones provided by Dispatchers.Default, Dispatchers.IO, or Dispatchers.Main.
Specifically, I want to:
Create a dispatcher that uses a pool of pre-defined threads.
Ensure that tasks are executed in a round-robin fashion across these threads.
Handle thread shutdown and cleanup gracefully.
I've found some basic examples of custom dispatchers, but they don't cover more advanced threading models or cleanup mechanisms. Could someone provide a detailed example or guide on how to achieve this?
I attempted to implement a custom coroutine dispatcher in Kotlin. I reviewed the documentation and basic examples available for creating custom dispatchers. I explored using CoroutineDispatcher and AbstractCoroutineContextElement to define a dispatcher that would utilize a pool of pre-defined threads. However, my attempts were not successful in achieving the specific threading model requirements I have.

Please provide some examples on what you have tried and why it wasn't sufficient for your case.
